# How to count occurrences of a node in SQL XML?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a count on the number of occurrences of the "Colors" node but have been so far unsuccessful.

Below is what I have tried so far.

If I have the following logic:

```
DECLARE @MyXML XML
SET @MyXML = '<SampleXML>
<Colors>
<Color1>White</Color1>
<Color2>Blue</Color2>
<Color3>Black</Color3>
<Color4 Special="Light">Green</Color4>
<Color5>Red</Color5>
</Colors>
<Fruits>
<Fruits1>Apple</Fruits1>
<Fruits2>Pineapple</Fruits2>
<Fruits3>Grapes</Fruits3>
<Fruits4>Melon</Fruits4>
</Fruits>
</SampleXML>'

SELECT
count(a.b.value('Colors','varchar(10)')) AS Color1
FROM @MyXML.nodes('SampleXML') a(b)
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Line 50
>   XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Comment: Would the result be `1` for your sample XML?

Comment: @MikaelEriksson  Sorry, that was in tehre by mistake, it was failing

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will count the number of Colors nodes which is `1`.

```
select @MyXML.value('count(/SampleXML/Colors)', 'int')
```

This will count the number of rows in `Colors` which is `5`.

```
select @MyXML.value('count(/SampleXML/Colors/*)', 'int')
```

Comment: Note to anyone reading this, the c in count must be lower case!   Otherwise you get this error: XQuery [XmlData.xmlDoc.value()]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:Count()'

Answer (score 7):

```
select @MyXML.value('count(/SampleXML/Colors)', 'INT') AS 'Count'
```

Comment: Ok, didn't see the parent /SampleXML at first, but don't think it needed a downvote